# Передача данных между классами java

Tags: java

Возможно вопрос покажется простым, но я конкретно торможу и у меня не получается передать переменную из одного класса в другой(

Есть класс `Recieve`, в мейне которого есть методы:

```
        public int receivedId(String recievedid){
                int id;
                return id=Integer.parseInt(recievedid);
            }
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                    throws IOException {
                String id = new String(body, "UTF-8");
                receivedId(id);
            }
```

я хочу переменную `id`, которую возвращает метод `receivedId`, передать новому классу. Для этого, как я понимаю, в новом классе нужно создать объект класса `Recieve`, но дальше я подвис.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Пример передачи данных между классами:

```
class Class1 {
    private String id = 1;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

}

class Class2 {
    private String id;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    Class2 class2 = new Class2();

    String id = class1.getId();
    class2.setId(id);
}
```

Создаём объекты классов `class1` и `class2`. Получаем `id` объекта `class1`. Задаём полученное значение для поля `id` объекта `class2`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно передать таким образом.

```
       public class ClassA {
    static int a;

    ClassA() {
        a = 20;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        int sum = b.sumAB();
        System.out.print(sum);
    }
}

class ClassB {
    int b;

    ClassB() {
        b = 10;
    }

    int sumAB() {
        return b+ClassA.a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае я обошелся созданием public статической переменной в классе (откуда получаю значение). Далее присовил это значение этой переменной. В другом классе где нужно получить значение я получаю значение из неё.