# как передавать значения переменных из одного класса в другой? java

Tags: java, классы

мне надо из классов "Vozdyx", "Azot", и др передать результаты вычислений (MCp, Mcv, U и др) и вывести их на экран. сам проект по ссылке ниже.

https://cloud.mail.ru/public/DCmk/N1aNVy1ce

Comment: тут уже есть какой-та ответ (такой же вопрос уже кто-то до тебя задавал...)
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501129/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-java

Comment: @rjhdby я ему эту же страницу и написал :-)

Comment: @Tode в подобных случаях надо пользоваться кнопочками "закрыть"(если недоступно, то "тревога") и выбирать "Дубликат вопроса"